# How to include the VCRT in WinRT appxupload package?

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, dependencies, windows-8.1, visual-c++-runtime

We have a WinRT app that uses SQLite, which in turn depends on the Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Runtime. When we package it up for submission, if I examine the output files, I see that the AppxManifest.xml file correctly lists the dependency:

```
<Dependencies>
  <PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.120.00" MinVersion="12.0.21005.1"/>
</Dependencies>
```

I am also able to find `sqlite3.dll` in the package for each architecture. What I can't seem to find is the Visual C++ runtime. Does this need to be in the package? Or will the Windows Store app installer process automatically download and install this for us, simply as a result of listing it as a dependency?

The reason I'm trying to get to the bottom of this is that our app failed certification the first time we submitted because on ARM machines it failed to start. However, it runs just fine for us on all architectures. This makes me suspect it's a dependency not being installed properly.

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Runtime dependency is fulfilled directly by the Store if your app correctly specified it in the AppXmanifest.xml.  See this:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/28/10354327.aspx

You don't need to include the C++ Runtime DLLs in the app package.